# Where should we compute the determinant and trace of a matrix?

Tags: matrices

In the matrix ring $M_3(\mathbb{Z}_6)$, what is the determinant of the matrix diag($3,3,1$)? Is it $9$ with respect to the integers or is it $3$ modulo $6$? How about its trace?

Comment: The elements of the matrix are elements of $\Bbb Z_6$ hence so are their sums and products.

Comment: It is $9\equiv 3\pmod 6$. The trace is $7\equiv 1\pmod 6$. I'm not sure off the top of my head if determinant and trace are well-defined over a non-field though, but I assume so.

Comment: @pancini I think they are perfectly well-defined over any ring as they are polynomials in the entries!

Comment: @JosephHarrison I mean for any choice of basis though

Answer (score 1):

You can compute the determinant and trace of the matrix in the integers and then reduce modulo $6$ at the end, or you can reduce the entries as you go. This is because determinant and trace are polynomials in the entries of a matrix and because the reduction modulo $6$ map $\mathbf{Z} \to \mathbf{Z}_6$ is a ring homomorphism. Don't worry if you don't understand this last part.

For example, the determinant and trace of $\text{diag}(3, 3, 1)$ are $9$ and $7$ in the integers, but as an element of $\mathbf{Z}_6$, we get $9 \equiv 3 \, (\text{mod} \, 6)$ and $7 \equiv 1 \, (\text{mod} \, 6)$.

I hope this helps!